# What are MinimalBookmark limitations in NSURLBookmarkCreationOptions?

Tags: macos, nsurl, nsfilemanager, bookmarks, finder

I at first use SuitableForBookmarkFile. However, the database I store the bookmark takes 200MB. Then I change to MinimalBookmark, the database only takes 98KB. That is 1/2040 of 200MB.

In Apple's doc, it says

> Specifies that a bookmark created with this option should be created
>   with minimal information. This produces a smaller bookmark that can be
>   resolved in fewer ways.

Anyone could further explain on this? Thanks.

Owen